# How to best sort a list of SPListItems from multiple lists?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007, lambda

My question is more of a "Is there a better way to do it" question then a "How do I do it" question. My code is as follows:

```
private List<SPListItem> GetListItemsFromSite(SPSite spSite)
{
    List<SPListItem> listItems = new List<SPListItem>();

    List<SPList> documentLibrariesInSite = GetCustomDocumentLibrariesInSite(spSite);
    foreach (SPList spList in documentLibrariesInSite)
    {
        SPListItemCollection itemCollection = GetLatestDocumentsFromSPList(spList);
        foreach(SPListItem item in itemCollection)
        {
            listItems.Add(item);
        }
    }
    listItems.Sort((x, y) => ((DateTime) x[SPBuiltInFieldId.Created]).CompareTo(((DateTime) y[SPBuiltInFieldId.Created])));
    listItems.Reverse();
    return listItems;
}

private SPListItemCollection GetLatestDocumentsFromSPList(SPList spList)
{
    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
    query.Query = "<Where><Gt><FieldRef Name=\"Created\" /><Value Type=\"DateTime\"><Today OffsetDays=\"-7\"</Value></Gt></Where>";
    query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
    query.RowLimit = NumberOfDocumentsToGet;
    SPListItemCollection listItemCollection = spList.GetItems(query);
    return listItemCollection;
}

private List<SPList> GetCustomDocumentLibrariesInSite(SPSite spSite)
{
    List<SPList> listCollection = new List<SPList>();
    foreach (SPWeb spWeb in spSite.AllWebs)
    {
        foreach (SPList spList in spWeb.Lists)
        {
            if (spList.TemplateFeatureId == CustomContentTypeFeatureGuid)
            {
                listCollection.Add(spList);
            }
        }
        spWeb.Dispose();
    }
    return listCollection;
}
```

Since I want the list items sorted by created date before i return the items i do a sort based on the CreatedDate field on the SPListItem. I also dont use the SPSiteDataQuery because i want to manipulate the SPListItems that i get.

Now the question is if i have any ways of doing this more efficient or "cleaner"? Any thoughts on the matter are welcome.

Comment: I guess this is the best and most convenient way of doing it. I have yet to find a better way to sort list items from several lists.

Answer (score 1):

you could add an orderby clause to your query AFTER the where clause

**Ascending**

```
<OrderBy> 
   <FieldRef Name="Created" Ascending="True" />
</OrderBy>
```

**Descending**

```
<OrderBy> 
   <FieldRef Name="Created" Ascending="false" />
</OrderBy>
```

Comment: Yes, but that would only order the items from the one list i query, not the final result i send back when i call the GetListItemsFromSite method. And it is the end result i want sorted, so it really doesn't matter what order the items from the SPQuery are in. In fact i had a <OrderBy> in the code, but took it away as it seemed redundant to sort the result two times.

Comment: the code does the same as you are doing and means you could remove the lines `listItems.Sort((x, y) => ((DateTime) x[SPBuiltInFieldId.Created]).CompareTo(((DateTime) y[SPBuiltInFieldId.Created])));     listItems.Reverse(); `, do you want to sort the listCollections instead?

Comment: No, OrderBy would only sort list items that i got from the query of one list, not all items returned from all lists.

Answer (score 0):

If the items in your custom lists have a common managed property or set of properties, you could build a custom search scope for them and query this scope instead of traversing each list individually. However, this will not work if you need real time results, but if you set up your incremental crawls to run frequently enough, you could get your items much faster and easier, especially if you have many of those custom lists.